React Native modal voice accessibility
Working on accessibility (voice) on my ReactNative Expo app, debugging with voiceOver.
How to focus the accessibility focus on the modal when it has been opened and make the content behind unaccessible?
Tried to build a custom hook which detects open elements and focus on them, but every time I open the modals, the focus just jumps to the first accessible element of my app.
